# How to change the content-type of the files in Azure blob Storage using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, content-type

I have a container set with sub folders and images in the Azure Blob Storage.
When I try to use these files it says the content type is miss-matched and when I check the content-Type it says `application/octet-stream`.

I want to change the content type from `application/octet-stream` to `image/jpeg` by using Azure Data Factory.

Is there any way to change the content type of all the files present in all containers and subfolders in containers using Azure Data Factory?

If there is any way to change the content type by using Azure Data Factory please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

As per community information using azure data factory. Unfortunately is not provided in this service ***The file is displayed if the setting is text/html. It is downloaded if the option is set to application/octet-stream at present you can't alter.***

Please check this [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/470237/how-to-set-content-type-when-copy-to-blob-storage.html) by [MartinJaffer-MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/users/85053/martinjaffer-msft.html)

Alternatively, you can change content type from `application/octet-stream` to `image/jpeg` by using Azure blob storage. Microsoft Storage Explorer, or any other product on the market, does not offer this feature. This feature also having some kind of dependency and limitation excluding limitation this can be possible in these steps.

[image]

select ***set-properties***

[image]

***In properties -> select content type should be Assign Content Type based on Blob Extension-> task -> submit***

[image]